# Macports on OSX 10.9 - compile with -stdlib=libstdc++

Tags: c++, opencv, clang, macports

In OSX 10.9 the default `-stdlib` option for clang++ is `libc++`, so that's what Macport uses when building packages.
Is there any way to tell Macports to use `libstdc++` instead?

In particular I would like to build OpenCV through Macports so it's using `libstdc++`, but I imagine I'll run into a need to do so for other packages as well

Comment: Why would you like to do this?

Comment: Because otherwise my builds break. My main compiler is g++ and it's quite likely other libs I use rely on libstdc++ too. In short I have build fine the same code on OSX 10.8 and the only difference I see is that OpenCV on my 10.9 machine relies on libc++, while on 10.8 machine on libstdc++.

Comment: why does your build break? It might be a problem in any of your code, libstdc++ or libc++.

Comment: It might of course. Here's what I know - the same code builds on osx 10.8 but breaks on linking with undefined symbols on 10.9. Library that fails to link is OpenCV, but I know it is present, lib path set, etc. Looking through what OpenCV lib links to, the only difference between two machines is that one that on 10.8 OpenCV links to libstdc++ and on 10.9 to libc++. Also the errors right after undefined OpenCV symbols are all about std::strings family, which is the common symptom of of libstdc++ and libc++ clash.

Comment: you need to recompile OpenCV with libc++ of course. They're not binary compatible...

Comment: Read the macports development list - in practice you need to stick to one std library and all the macports is built with clang and libc++ so much easier for you to use these.

Answer (score 4):

The option is simply: `-stdlib=libstdc++`

If you need finer control over the build process for various ports, you can always set variables like:
`CXX = "clang -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++`, `CXXFLAGS = "-Wall -O2 -march=core2"`, etc.

And build `<port>` from source:

```
sudo port -s install <port> -universal \  
configure.cc="${CC}" configure.cxx="${CXX}" \  
configure.cflags="${CFLAGS}" configure.cxxflags="${CXXFLAGS}"
```

The other alternative, is to install the `gcc48` (or above) port, and use it as the compiler. Don't use the old gcc-4.2.1 installed with older versions of Xcode. It's rubbish.

Comment: Strange, Macports accepts those options, but doesn't honour them. I removed OpenCV library, build it passing CXX flag that with `-stdlib=libstdc++` and still built library was linking to libc++.

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish this appears to be to build opencv from source, and use the configure.cxx_stdlib variable to specify libstdc++ as your C++ runtime.

Try out the following:

```
sudo port install -s opencv configure.cxx_stdlib="libstdc++"
```

Comment: Aaa, sorry, I have changed jobs and can't even check out if your answer solves the issue ><