# Macports on OSX 10.11 - compile "older" ports with -stdlib=libstdc++

Tags: c++, macos, boost, macports, libstdc++

Macports uses the default `-stdlib` option which is `libc++` on OSX 10.11. However, I need to use `libstdc++` because I use other libraries rely on that. Up to this point, this question is the same with the following two questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600350/macports-on-osx-10-9-compile-opencv-with-libstdc) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546810/macports-on-osx-10-9-compile-with-stdlib-libstdc), and I know the answer is `sudo port install PORTNAME configure.cxx_stdlib="libstdc++"`.

However, I need to install an older port (specifically Boost 1.52) and the way to do it is to check out the port's directory at the desired revision using the `svn` command (which creates a directory called PORTNAME in the current location, and populates that with everything the port needs to build) and then we install the port as follows:

```
$ cd PORTNAME
$ sudo port install
```

If I add `configure.cxx_stdlib="libstdc++"` to the end of the install command, macports does not honor the request. I edit the `Portfile` of the downloaded older port manually and add the instruction there but that didn't workout. I edit the `macports.conf` file but this didn't workout either...

TL;DR, how do we compile an "older" port with `libstdc++` on OSX 10.11?

Comment: just build it from source as per the boost website?

Comment: Thanks Richard Hodges, as a last resort, I did as you suggested. But still, I want to know if it is doable with macports and learn how to do it.

Comment: can't help there. I've never managed to get macports to work reliably. I build everything from source. I find it easer and more controllable. I use separate build trees for each toolchain variant so there's no confusion. e.g. `build/c++14-libc++/local_system/...` and `build/c++14-libc++/ios/...` etc.

Comment: @HalilŞEN, if you want this reopened, let me know. I didn't know I had the power to close this as a duplicate all by myself.

Comment: However, I strongly suggest that you do not want to do this. libc++ and libstdc++ are not compatible. You'll inadvertently break a lot of the tools you use by switching from one library to another, particularly so with Boost. There are lots of tools that depend on Boost. I suggest you instead rebuild the small bit of stuff that you built using libstdc++ with the clang rather than gcc.

Comment: @DavidHammen Well I would like it to be reopened because as I explained in the question, this is a different issue and the answers of the similar questions does not resolve it.

Comment: @DavidHammen The issue is that I am the end-user of the library which is compiled against `libstdc++`. So that is not an option for me. Is there a way to set the default `stdlib` as `libstdc++` on macports so that every port will be compiled against it?

Comment: @RichardHodges I am definitely having hard time too and me being a mac/unix rookie does not help at all! It seems that if nobody responds with a reliable answer, I will have to choose your path as well. Thanks anyways

Comment: @HalilŞEN programming for Linux is like going to a shop and getting everything you want, every time, with no hassle or stress. Programming Apple products is like paying for a dominatrix - it hurts but is strangely fulfilling once you get into it. Programming for Microsoft is like being repeatedly made to walk into a brick wall by your gaolers and threatened with death if you want to leave.

Comment: @RichardHodges Nice analogy. However, I must admit that I was pretty happy on the Microsoft side, mostly thanks to visual studio.. But again, I am just coding algorithms and developing solvers, so there is nothing really OS dependent going on...